# How to separate out the tooltip text from the HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I am using [this plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) for tooltip. It uses `title` attribute as tooltip text placeholder. There are too many tooltip text, I would like to put them all in a place in order to maintain or update easily. What could be a good approach?

My idea is to create a map in js file, eg:

```
var tooltiptext =
[{
"label_1": "description for label 1",
"label_2": "description for label 2",
"label_3": "description for label 3",
...
}]
```

And use jquery to add these title content into the page in `$(document).ready`.
Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't event need the square braces. Let's assume that the `label` in the object represents the ID of the element. Then use:

```
var tooltiptext = {
    "label_1": "description for label 1",
    "label_2": "description for label 2",
    "label_3": "description for label 3",
    //....
    "label_n": "description for label n"
};
$.each(tooltiptext, function(label, title){
    $("#" + label).attr("title", title).tooltip();
});
```

Inside the loop, you're setting the `title` *attribute* of the element. Then, `tooltip` is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to divert you away from the path you have chosen, if I can.

Putting the tooltip into the HTML itself as a title attribute is much better because...

1. It will make sense to you as the developer - the text is where it will be used, so you can see the context it is being used in. If you have a JavaScript file containing these resources, you will be relying on the label to tell you where the text is being used and as the list grows this will become troublesome.
2. It will just work! If JavaScript is disabled, or the device doesn't run JavaScript, or you have an error in your JavaScript, the title attribute will still cause a tooltip to be displayed - it may not look as pretty as a cool JavaScript tooltip, but you can guarantee all of your users can get the information in the tooltip.
3. Later on, if you support multiple languages or get your content from a content management system, you will want to inject the text via the server, not via JavaScript - by placing the text in the title tag, you make it available to your JavaScript, so you no longer need to keep your JavaScript in sync with your content management system and you don't need to get translated versions of your JavaScript text resource.

I hope this helps you to make up your mind.

Comment: I agree your point. However, this is a django project and the labels are populated dynamically. That being said, in the template, it's a line of code: {% for label_name in labels %}. What will you do in this case?

Comment: I am writing a lot of sites using MVC at the moment and I write resources into HTML attributes, as I localise the language based on the user location - this may or may not work for you, so you'd have to make a judgement call.